# How to verify the Riemann hypothesis up to a given height?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

According to the Wikipedia article on [`Riemann hypothesis`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis#Location_of_the_zeros),

> The number of zeros of the zeta function with imaginary part between $0$ and $T$ is given by
> $$N(T)=\frac{1}{\pi}\operatorname{Arg}\left(\xi\left(\frac{1}{2}+iT\right)\right)$$
> where $\xi$ is Riemann's xi function and **the argument is defined by varying it continuously along the line with $\Im (s)=T$, starting with argument $0$ at $\infty+iT$.**

A formula like this is a part of verifying the Riemann hypothesis up to a given height. How can I implement it in Mathematica? $\xi$ is `RiemannXi`, but $\operatorname{Arg}$ is not the same as the usual `Arg` function.